# fancybox content resize to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fancybox

I am using the fancybox plugin on the webpage that I am working on, but right now I am using iframes to load my external html content. I am not too familiar with ajax, but from reading other posts I have found that using iframes will not work as well as using ajax. How would I use jquery and ajax to load my html file into the fancybox content and then resize it to the width and height of the content of the html file I have. Here is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
//import all the needed javascript and css files for jquery and plugins
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic'
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="sample1.html" class="fancybox">Open Fancybox</a>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a onComplete event (or your own event, for example after clicking some link inside FancyBox window) and in this event you have to write code:

```
$.fancybox.resize
```

The loading is easy:

```
$('#fancybox_content').load('ajax/test.html')
```

For ajax syntax see 
[.load() call doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Ok it didn't work. I have a different question though. If I have my external test.html page, how do I access the width and height of the body of that page.

Comment: If that didn't work, how come this is a correct answer? just wondering